# Can Outlook filter emails that have not received any answer?

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-addin

I need to send many emails to near 100 persons each day - so I need to track resolution of some questions.

Is it possible to list the recipients that haven't replied to a particular email?

Or move (copy) these emails without any answer to a separate folder, etc?

Thanks.

Comment: Outlook version and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a rule to move responses to a specific folder based on a distribution group and then write an app that could look at that folder and compare it to the distribution list to see who hasn't responded.